# pg_dump failing after aws rds upgraded postgres version to 9.6.6 while the installed version in the environment is 9.3.2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, virtualenv, amazon-rds

I upgraded the version of aws rds postgres to 9.6.6 and now there is a mismatch in my virtualenv and the actual server postgres versions.If I should do the upgrade in the venv, Should I use yum or pg_upgrade? Will upgrading the installed version in the environment in the server from 9.3.2 to 9.6.6 cause any problems?

Error showing up is:

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.6.6; pg_dump version: 9.3.22

pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. You can solve it by installing `postgres96`. It may install a different minor version (9.6.>11< for instance) but `pg_dump` should work just fine.

```
sudo yum install postgres96
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded postgres to Postgres-Server96 and pg_dump is working fine.

Comment: Right now my postgresServer version after update with yum is in 9.6.8 while server is running on 9.6.6 which I don't know, Can be a problem??